# Rerunning stored procedure returns previous resultset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2019

Using Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2019.

I am writing an application that calculates total waste costs spent.  To calculate this, I need the waste cost per material per kg.  This cost can change from year to year.

These waste costs are stored in a database.  When the application loads, these costs are collected by a stored procedure.  This is a dynamic result set.  It loads the last x years of data (where x is determined by the user).  This stored procedure takes the start year as input parameter (smallint) and collects all the data starting from that year.  This means I have a result set that can have a different number of columns, with different column names.

If I collect the last 5 years.  I would get a table back with the columns <Material|2017|2018|2019|2020|2021>.

The user can add a year.  The costs of the last year are than copied to the new year (this happens in the database).  After that, the application will load the last x years from the database again.  This is where it goes wrong.

I rerun the stored procedure that collects the waste costs for the last x years.  The correct parameter value (start year) is given by the application and the correct data is returned by the database.  (In the stored procedure I write the input & output to separate tables for debugging, so I'm sure of this!)  The returned data table I see in C# holds the previous columns I've collected from the database.

My code:

```cs
public DataTable SpDataTableOutput(string spName, SpParameter[] param)
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, db);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable resultSet = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        // Add parameters
        this.AddParameters(param, cmd);
        this.AddReturnValue(cmd);

        // Get the results
        db.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(resultSet);
        db.Close();

        // Get the return value
        int returnValue = GetReturnValue(cmd);

        // If the sp fails, throw an exception
        if (returnValue != 0)
            throw new Exception("The database returned a return value of " + Convert.ToString(returnValue));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to run sp '" + spName + "'", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        adapter.Dispose();
        adapter = null;

        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd = null;

        db.Dispose();
        db = null;
    }

    return resultSet;
}
```

The issue is not in the stored procedure.  It's in the method above.  Debugging it, I see the correct parameter is given to the database, in the database I see that the correct input parameter was given and the correct result set was returned.  When I check the returned data table in `adapter.Fill(resultSet);`, I see the previous data set.

For example, the start columns are: <Material|2017|2018|2019|2020|2021>.

If I add a year, I would expect <Material|2018|2019|2020|2021|2022> (which is what the database returns), but I get <Material|2017|2018|2019|2020|2021>.

If I add another year, I would expect <Material|2019|2020|2021|2022|2023>, but still get <Material|2017|2018|2019|2020|2021>.

I'm assuming this is a cache issue, as it doesn't happen always (just most of the times).
Also, if I change the number of years I want to see displayed (without refreshing the data) and add a year, the data is always correctly refreshed (this does mean the stored procedure returns a different number of columns).

Last, I've seen this happen after I add a year, close the application and restart it (all in debug mode).  The initial waste cost load just doesn't display the new year even though the data is in the db.

I hope this is clear.

How can I get a fresh data set every time I run the method above?

The stored procedure - this has been tested and works perfect

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetWasteCost_v01]

-- Parameters for the stored procedure
@ipStartYear smallint

AS
BEGIN


-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @varTimeStamp datetime
SET @varTimeStamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

-- DEBUG --
INSERT INTO z_InputParam (
            InsertTime,
            StartYear)
    VALUES (
            @varTimeStamp,
            @ipStartYear)
-- DEBUG --

-- Generate the resultset
DECLARE @varMaxYear smallint

SELECT @varMaxYear = MAX([Year])
    FROM dbo.WasteCosts

CREATE TABLE #tblResults (
            MaterialID int,
            Material varchar(100))

-- Add a column for each year
DECLARE @varCnt int
SET @varCnt = @ipStartYear

DECLARE @varLiteral varchar(MAX)

WHILE (@varCnt <= @varMaxYear) BEGIN

    SET @varLiteral = 'ALTER TABLE #tblResults ADD [' + CAST(@varLoopCnt AS varchar(4)) + '] decimal(10,4) NULL'
    EXEC(@varLiteral)

    SET @varCnt = @varCnt + 1

END

-- Fill the dataset
INSERT INTO #tblResults (
            MaterialID,
            Material)
    SELECT DISTINCT
            M.MaterialID,
            M.CatNo,
            M.[Description]
        FROM dbo.tbl_Material M
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_WasteCost WC
                ON M.MaterialID = WC.MaterialID
        WHERE WC.[Year] BETWEEN @ipStartYear AND @varMaxYear

-- Get the data for each year
SET @varCnt = @ipStartYear

WHILE (@varCnt <= @varMaxYear) BEGIN

    SET @varLiteral =
        'UPDATE RS ' +
                    'SET RS.[' + CAST(@varCnt AS varchar(4)) + '] = WC.WasteCost ' +
            'FROM #tblResults RS ' +
                'INNER JOIN dbo.WasteCost WC ' +
                    'ON RS.MaterialID = WC.MaterialID ' +
            'WHERE WC.[Year] = ' + CAST(@varCnt AS varchar(4))

    EXEC(@varLiteral)

    SET @varCnt = @varCnt + 1

END

-- DEBUG --
INSERT INTO z_Output (
            InsertTime,
            ColumnName)
    SELECT
            @varTimeStamp,
            CAST(C.[name] AS varchar(100))
        FROM tempdb.sys.columns C
        WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#tblResults');
-- DEBUG --

-- Return the resultset
SELECT
            RS.*
    FROM #tblResults RS
    ORDER BY CatNo

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #tblResultSet


END
```

Parameter code - This works and is been tested thoroughly for the last 10 years or so.

```cs
private void AddParameters(SpParameter[] param, SqlCommand cmd)
{
    foreach (SpParameter parameter in param)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter.GetParameter());
    }
}


private void AddReturnValue(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    
    SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
}


public SqlParameter GetParameter()
{
    // Create the return paramter
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(this.Name, this.Type);

    // Set direction & nullable
    param.Direction = this.Direction;
    param.IsNullable = this.IsNullable;

    // Set value
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case (SqlDbType.BigInt):
        case (SqlDbType.Int):
        case (SqlDbType.SmallInt):
        case (SqlDbType.TinyInt):
            if (this.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.Value);
            break;
        case (SqlDbType.Bit):
            if (this.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Value);
            break;
        case (SqlDbType.Decimal):
        case (SqlDbType.Float):
        case (SqlDbType.Real):
            if (this.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = Convert.ToDouble(this.Value);
            break;
        case (SqlDbType.Char):
        case (SqlDbType.NChar):
        case (SqlDbType.VarChar):
        case (SqlDbType.NVarChar):
        case (SqlDbType.Xml):
            if (this.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = this.Value;
            break;
        case (SqlDbType.VarBinary):
            if (this.VarBinaryValue == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = this.VarBinaryValue;
            break;
        case (SqlDbType.DateTime):
            if (this.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                param.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Value);
            break;
    }

    // Return the parameter
    return param;
}
```

Comment: You have to show stored procedure and parameters code

Comment: I've added the sp and the parameter code, but these are not the issue.  They do work.  I've checked the parameter on the SqlCommand.  It has the coorrect value.  The dataset returned has the correct columns.

Comment: The only way that I can conceive of that all of the above statements could be true, is if the caching is occurring in the *code that calls* `SpDataTableOutput(..)`.  There is nothing in the C# code, nor the SQL code, nor SQL Server that you have shown us that would act like this (retaining a dynamic dataset over application invocations and re-connections) and it would take a bug in the client SQL Server access drivers so severe that it would be very well known.  So it's either the calling code/application, or something that you think is confirmed, is not actually happening.

Comment: And how are the tables defined that are used in this code? (The tables: `WasteCosts`, `tbl_Material`, `tbl_WasteCost`)    Also the table `#tblResults` is defined with the fields `MaterialID` and `Material`. How can it be use with an ORDER BY `CatNo` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly causes this issue.  It becomes worse over time.  The issue persists even after I reboot my machine.  So it's not a bug in the code.  Something else must be causing this.

In the end I got rid of the stored procedure.  I create the dataset in the code, using select queries.